# yeoman install error mac

Tags: node.js, yeoman

i get this errors in yeoman installation.  anyone knows what might be the issue?

```
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/shelljs/scripts/generate-docs.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Gwit
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.32
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/shelljs/scripts/generate-docs.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/shelljs/scripts/generate-docs.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/nopt'
npm ERR! error rolling back  yo@1.1.2 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/nopt']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/nopt' }
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: chalk@'^0.4.0'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.0","0.1.1","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.3.0","0.4.0","0.5.0","0.5.1"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:719:10)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:641:10
npm ERR!     at RegClient.get_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:101:14)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:37:12)
npm ERR!     at fs.js:266:14
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Gwit
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.32
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/actions/fetch.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Gwit
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.32
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/actions/fetch.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/actions/fetch.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/has-color
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Gwit
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.32
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/configstore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/configstore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/object-assign
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
```

I am trying to find what is the problem with no luck.  I google it but I could not find any answers.  anyone had any ideas?

Comment: Hm weird... mabye try `npm update -g` before?

Comment: solved it by uninstalling node and npm an re-installing from scratch